# Attachments not saving in an Enterprise Geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-server, esri-geodatabase, arcgis-online, attachments

I have an ArcGIS Server 10.2.2 feature service.  The feature classes are saved in a SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Geodatabase.  The feature classes have attachments enabled.  They are non-versioned and have archiving enabled to allow syncing and offline editing.  I've added the feature service to ArcGIS Online.  I can edit the feature classes and add attachments with no errors.  But when I close the editor window and then identify the feature it says 'No Attachments Found'.  When I look at the geodatabase on the server there is a record in the __ATTACH table but when I Identify a feature it doesn't show any attachments.  Has anyone successfully setup attachments on a 10.2.2 feature service in an Enterprise Geodatabase?

Answer (score 1):

After enabling attachments on the input table or feature class,

> run the **Generate Attachment Match Table tool** to create a match table
>   that will assist you in associating the records from the input table
>   with files on disk. Input to this tool consists of an Input Folder
>   which contains the files to be attached and a Key Field. The tool
>   works by iterating through each row in the input table and comparing
>   the value from that row's Key Field to all of the files in the Input
>   Folder. A match is found when the base name (file name without file
>   extension) for the file matches the value in the key field. The output
>   created contains a field named MATCHID (the ObjectID from the input
>   table or feature class) and a field named FILENAME (the file path to
>   the matched file)

Required is
**Input Folder**
MATCHID (the ObjectID) and a field named FILENAME must match

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000017z000000